# Create string template in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

I would like to store a string as a constant in Swift so I can reuse it and inject variables into it. For example, I can do this in C#:

```cs
var template = "Your name is {0} and your age is {1}."
someLabel.text = string.Format(template, "John", 35)
some2Label.text = string.Format(template, "Jane", 33)
```

How can I accomplish this in Swift so I can reuse the string template?

Comment: Swift can call Objective-C Cocoa methods, so look into NSString's `stringWithFormat:` method - it works just as well in Swift as it does in Objective-C.

Comment: Thankfully I skipped Objective-C so no idea.

Comment: But that's not the point. The point is that the docs are still the docs. Read the docs on NSString. It's all there.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use swift's `printf`-style syntax to save the template and then use it like this:

```
var template = "Your name is %@ and your age is %d."
someLabel.text = String(format: template, "John", 35)
some2Label.text = String(format: template, "Jane", 33)
```

If you haven't used this style of syntax before here is a rough guide:

- `%@` : String (or, as nhgrif pointed out, the `description` / `descriptionWithLocale` property of an `NSObject`)
- `%d` : Int
- `%f` : Double
- `%.2f` : Double with precision of 2, e.g. 2.2342 -> 2.23

[Here's the documentation if you require more precision.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: `%@` is for more than just `String`.

Comment: Good answer (Voted). I wonder if you could use a Swift-style format string as a parameter as well? `let aString = "John has \(count) jellybeans"; let newString = String(format: aString, count)`

Answer (score 7):

You already have an answer, but if you want type safety and to localize your code, you can use enums like this:

```
enum Greeting: CustomStringConvertible {

    case SayHello(String)

    var description:String {
        switch (self) {
        case .SayHello(let name):
            return "Say hello to \(name)?"
        }
    }
}

let a = Greeting.SayHello("my little friend")
```

Note that doesn't preclude you from taking a hybrid approach of putting all your string templates in one location and building them in a type safe enum via the `String(format:...)` approach.  You would just need to implement it carefully (but only once).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template engine such as https://github.com/groue/GRMustache.swift.